Isomorphism Between the Group of Isometries of an Equilateral Triangle and $( S_3 )$
Let $G$ be the group of isometries of the Euclidean affine plane that leave an equilateral triangle $∆$ invariant. I need help proving that $G$ is isomorphic to $( S_3 )$.
$S_3$ denotes the group of permutations of the set {1,2,3}.
What I have concluded is that maybe I need to find a bijection (a one-to-one correspondence) between the elements of  $G$ and the elements of $( S_3 )$, such that the composition of elements in $G $ corresponds to the composition of elements in $( S_3 )$.

It is a good thing to have written down the definition of what a group isomorphism is, but now please show some attempt. (Or browse on this site, as this is certainly a duplicate.)

Sure, can I edit the question now and add the definition of group isomorphism , or is it unnecessary?

You already did (after "What I have concluded is that maybe"). My comment meant: please go on.
